# implementing an 8 out of 12 discontinue rule in a task

Tags: python

I hope someone can help, I'm working on implementing an assessment task (testing children's maths skills using the [Gorilla](https://www.gorilla.sc) online platform). Our task has an unusual discontinue (exit) rule of quit at 8 incorrect answers out of the last 12 responses, and will require a bespoke script in the apps scripting tool using features from the Gorilla API using Python.

I'm fairly new to programming, especially Python. I was hoping someone could help me visualise the code for getting this to work. I've currently got it set to exit after 12 consecutive errors:

```
if(correct){
            currentConsecutiveIncorrect = 0;
            gorilla.store(_noCurrentConsecutiveIncorrectTrials, currentConsecutiveIncorrect, true);
        } else {
            currentConsecutiveIncorrect++;
            gorilla.store(_noCurrentConsecutiveIncorrectTrials, currentConsecutiveIncorrect, true);
            
            // If we are at or have exceeded our max number of consecutive incorrect trials, we need to end the task
            if(currentConsecutiveIncorrect >= _maxConsecutiveIncorrectTrials){
                gorilla.finish();
            }
        }
```

Although this works it is inflating the number of responses required before exit, and I'm worried about participant fatigue as there are over a hundred task items.

If it's not too much to ask, it would really help if someone could explain how to achieve this programmatically - not the code or how to implement it in Gorilla (I would like to figure that out as part of my learning). At the moment I just can't see how to theoretically achieve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly what your problem is, I'd say there is a logical issue.

If there are 8 errors out of the 12 last questions, you exit right ?

Let's take an exemple, if someone got 7 wrong errors then got a good answer, I believe with your  code you're resetting the count error. So the 9 could be wrong but no exit would happen.

```
if(correct){
            currentConsecutiveIncorrect = 0;
...
```

So my guess is that you should store every answers until you get 12 answers. Obviously checking for wrong answers every time.

That would give something like this (0 being good, 1 being wrong)

[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Then, if you still don't have 8 errors, delete the first value of the array, append the answer to the end of the list, then count how many errors are in the list.

Comment: Hi, Achille G, thank you and yes your assessment of the issue was correct. I just couldn't get my head around the logic, which sounds daft because it's almost painfully simple now that you have explained it. I'll give it a go today, now that I have the time.

Comment: Good to hear !
Best of luck to you